# What can I do to deal with a major civil having a high score than me?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

There are like 6 major civilizations in my game. Most of them have lower score than me, but one of them is higher than me, about 100.

I am a bit upset. What can I do to deal with this? Attack the civil? But it is far away across the ocean. Or use some diplomatic method?

Please shed some lights. Thanks!

Comment: Can you add some more details to your question? Which Civ are you playing as? What difficulty are you on? Which Civ is the one that is higher than you? Are you far enough in the game to have spies to get information on the Civ in question? Is this a standard game against AI, a scenario, or multiplayer? As it stands, your question is too vague for us to give you a very helpful answer.

Comment: Sorry about the big question. Actually I just registered and this is my first question. The question is very general, and I think the answer does help.

Comment: It is CIV5 gods and kings. Quite easy difficulty (the second easy as I recall). It is a standard game against AI. I do have spy now and I am sending them to the opponent city. I play by focusing on economic and military, and my technology advances quite quickly. I am just curious why that civil has so many score points and ideally I want to make it stopped advancing. :P

Answer (score 4):

You have to find out in which areas he is stronger, in which weaker.

**Is he behind in military?**
Either form an alliance with another civilization and capture some of his cities or expand aggressively and get more cities to get an advantage later.

**Is he behind in tech?**
That means he has slower research, focus on increasing your advantage so you get units that can kill 3 of his units on their own.

**Is he behind in economy**
Increase your advantage with trade routes and make some good trades with other civilizations. Use your money to buy core buildings/units to speed up your development.

**When all else fails...**
... bribe the other civilizations to go to war against him without you and boost them with money and strategic resources. Make sure your minions... uhm, the other civilizations are not so weak that they get taken over by your opponent, making him twice as strong as he was before.

**Alternative Solution**
Go to war against the weakest or one of the weaker civilization, take over all the cities and come out twice as strong yourself.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your civ and playstyle. Are you an economic-oriented civ? Build trade routes, get money, and bribe the city-states out from under him. Diplomatic? Form an alliance with one or more other civs and undermine the king of the hill. Civilization is about strategy and playing to your strengths.

As long as you maximize your strengths and minimize your weaknesses, you'll do fine. I tend to not play military-oriented civs so I can't help you there.

Comment: Thanks! I think it makes sense to the city-states under him. I will try it next time. Cheers!